# Why can't I create a new application using Rails new command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rvm

I think I might of messed with my RVM and didn't know it.

Whenever I use the Rails `new` command, I get an error saying it can't handle the JSON version.

I uninstalled Ruby and reinstalled v1.9.3 and then reinstalled Rails 4.0.1. Now I get a new error that is similar, just for a different gem.

```
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/build_info/coffee-script-source-1.6.3.info
An error occurred while installing coffee-script-source (1.6.3), and Bundler
cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install coffee-script-source -v '1.6.3'` succeeds before
bundling.
```

I have no idea what to do. I was wondering if anyone had any ideas on how to fix this problem.

Comment: Edit your question and append the output of `rvm info`. It looks like you've tried using `sudo` with an RVM managed Ruby but other things could be wrong too.

Comment: Needs `rvm info` output to disentangle this. Looks like an attempt to manage the system ruby environment using rvm. That's not what rvm is for. The point is to create local, per user instances of ruby versions, and per project instances of gemsets. Not to override the system installation.

Answer (score 0):

you missed to use rvm ruby:

```
rvm use ruby
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to run `gem install coffee-script-source -v '1.6.3'` as a the root user so that it can have access write to the gems install directory. You need to run: `rvmsudo gem install coffee-script-source -v '1.6.3'` this will sudo gem install it in the rvm context.

Answer (score -2):

`sudo chown jeff:jeff /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/build_info/`

should do the trick

Comment: No, this is WRONG. Do NOT chown the system-owned Ruby or any of its files or directories to the user. That is owned by the system and needs to remain that way.

Comment: Hi @theTinMan thanks for pointing that out! I'm terribly sorry for submitting this as answer. One should definitely not change the owner of the system ruby.